# ¿Cómo ordenar ascendente mente una pila que recibe elementos por un método?

Tags: java, pilas

Así se agregan los números a la pila ahora lo se tendrían que hacer es ordenarlos de menor a mayor utilizando únicamente pilas.

```
Pila pila = new Pila();
// Llena la pila.
pila.push( new Nodo(6) );
pila.push( new Nodo(9) );
pila.push( new Nodo(12) );
pila.push( new Nodo(62) );
pila.push( new Nodo(21) );
```

Comment: mira no sé si te sirva esto pero podrías implementar un método de ordenamiento burbuja o por inserción.
[ORDENAMIENTO DE BURBUJA (es muy simple)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_de_burbuja) [ORDENAMIENTO INSERCIÓN (mas complicado, pero mas rápido )](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_por_inserci%C3%B3n) espero te sirva de algo!

Comment: Solo por curiosidad. Cuando dices Pila, es eso un Stack?

Comment: Exacto lo mismo pense yo, seguro se reifiere a un Stack...
Aunque tambien puede ser una clase propia de su programa. Es importante que lo aclares.

Answer (score 0):

La forma más sencilla de hacerlo es utilizando dos pilas. La pila original, y una auxiliar.

Entonces lo que tienes que hacer es:

1. Si la pila está vacía, insertas el nodo
2. Si la pila no está vacía, comienzas a sacar elementos de la pila original y moverlos a la pila auxiliar. La condición para seguir sacando elementos de la pila original y moverlos a la auxiliar es `pila.isEmpty() && pila.peek().nodoValue > newNodeValue`, donde `newNodeValue` es el valor del nuevo nodo a insertar.
3. Ya que hayas encontrado un `peek` que sea menor al valor a insertar, puedes ingresar el nuevo nodo a la pila.
4. El paso final sería mover todos los valores de la pila auxiliar de regreso a la pila original.

Te dejo un repl.it con el código para que veas como funciona. En mi caso use el `Stack` que viene en `Java`, pero puedes hacer que funcione con la clase que tu hayas creado.
https://replit.com/@JacoboTapia/OrderedStack#Main.java

Answer (score -1):

Podrías enviar los datos de la pila a un array y ordenarlo:

```
int o = 0;
for(int i=0;!pila.empty;i++){
    vec[i] = pila.pop();//no estoy seguro si lo debuelve en int o hay que convertirlo
    o++;
}
vec.sort();//de forma ascendente
for(int i=0;i<=o;i++){
    pila.push(vec[i]);
}
```

Espero te sirva. ^-^